# Calculate age cluster dynamically in DAX - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a report for the HR department.  One of the visuals aims to display the pyramid of ages of the employees by gender (we take cluster of 5 years, e.g. 20-25 for people between 20 and 25 years old).

To make it simple, data wise, I have a table with the list of employees, including their date of birth and many other fields, not relevant for this post.  I added a calculated column with the age cluster based on the today’s date:

AgeCluster =

```
VAR AgeCalc=if(HR_DATA[Birthdate]=blank(),blank(),DATEDIFF(HR_DATA[Birthdate],today(),YEAR))

VAR Mult5=INT(AgeCalc/5)

RETURN

    if(isblank(AgeCalc),blank(),5*Mult5&"-"&5*(Mult5+1))
```

And I have a basic visual (tornado chart with the AgeCluster in Group, showing male and female)
[image: Tornado chart]

[image: Tornado chart settings]

Now my issue is that my report should be dynamic, so the user should be able to see the situation in the past or in the future...  I have a calendar table (not linked to my HR_Data table), and a date slicer on my report's page.  I need the age cluster to be recalculated.

I have tried a calculated table, but I can’t get it working properly.  I have read various blog posts on similar issue, but still can't figure out how to solve it...

Any idea or tips much appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic filtering usually means in these situations that you need a fixed x-axis to work with. That x-axis is calculated outside the original table, such as a parameter table.

Assuming your data looks like this:

### Table: Employees

| EmployeeID | DOB |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 March 1977 |
| 2 | 05 December 1981 |
| 3 | 25 December 1951 |
| 4 | 20 December 1954 |
| 5 | 04 March 1980 |
| 6 | 24 July 1968 |
| 7 | 07 June 1984 |
| 8 | 01 October 1992 |
| 9 | 25 February 1999 |
| 10 | 02 November 1987 |

First, we need to create the Age Groups with their respective lower and top bands. This table uses a similar code when a parameter table is created.

### Table: Buckets

Because you are using whole numbers, I think is best to calculate the TopBand by adding `4`. In that case, you don't have repeating numbers. In other words, ranges shouldn't overlap (`20-25` and `25-30`)

```
Buckets =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    GENERATESERIES ( 20, 80, 5 ),
    "Age Series",
        [Value] & " - " & [Value] + 4,
    "LowerBand", [Value],
    "TopBand", [Value] + 4
)
```

Also, we will need a Calendar Table to filter accordingly.

### Table: CalendarHR

```
CalendarHR =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR ( MIN ( Employees[DOB] ), TODAY () ),
    "Year", YEAR ( [Date] )
)
```

With all that, you can create a calculation that can be filter dynamically.

### DAX Measure:

```
EmployeesbyBracket = 
VAR _SelectedDate =
    MAX ( CalendarHR[Date] )
VAR _SelectedLowerBand =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Buckets[LowerBand] )
VAR _SelectedTopBand =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Buckets[TopBand] )
VAR EmployeesAge =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        Employees,
        "Age",
            INT ( DATEDIFF ( [DOB], _SelectedDate, YEAR ) / 5 ) * 5
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            EmployeesAge,
            [Age] >= _SelectedLowerBand
                && [Age] <= _SelectedTopBand
        )
    )
```

### Output

I've created a table visual with the `Age Groups` from the `Buckets` table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Angelo, you made my day.  Works fine.

Comment: Glad to help, can you also mark the answer as a solution if you found it helpful?